# How to crawl folders to index files?

Tags: python

I'm searching a possibility to crawl through a filesystem (similar to the 'tree' CMD command) to find every *.R3D file in all the folders/sub folders and index them. What's the most effective way to do that, while the load should be as small as possible?

Comment: Are you working on a Linux or Windows server? And does it have to be a Python solution, since you tagged your question with Pyton?

Comment: OSX, and yes, have to be Python.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to use a helper function that wraps [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk), like this:

```
import os

def filesByPattern(directory, matchFunc):
  for path,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for f in filter(matchFunc, path):
      yield os.path.join(path, f)

certainFolder = '.'
allR3DFiles = filesByPattern(certainFolder, lambda fn: fn.endswith('.R3D'))
```

Comment: +1, but a little too complicated to my taste. Posted an improved version in a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Improving on @phihag's example:

```
def all_files(directory):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for f in files:
            yield os.path.join(path, f)

r3d_files = [f for f in all_files(your_directory)
               if f.endswith('.R3D')]
```

Comment: Thanks alot everyone fr the quick replies.
This one only seem to output folder names, and not individual files.
`def all_files(directory):

    for path, files, dirs in os.walk(directory):
        print files
        for f in dirs:
            yield os.path.join(path, f)`

seem to do it

Comment: @user1095570: got some things in the wrong order, should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks @FredFoo for this answer. Better to add `sorted(files)` instead of just `files` in third line above, to ensure sorting items alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

[`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) does exactly that.

Example from link:

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
    print root, "consumes",
    print sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files),
    print "bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files"
    if 'CVS' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('CVS')  # don't visit CVS directories
```